# Employee stock options: why is the total number of shares a secret?

Tags: starting-out-investing, employee-stock-options

I know someone close to me who has been offered employee stock options (which they are supposed to buy later at a fixed price, potentially, when/if the business goes to IPO or something) and they asked for my advice.

I asked what is the total number of shares as I never invested in a business without understanding how much of it I’m buying.

However, the company refused to share this information on the basis that it is “confidential”.

It feels very strange since they have been bragging about how many millions they received in funding.

Do you consider for this to be a red flag?

Comment: Are the options being offered as a perq? Does the person actually work their yet? Or are these being offered for purchase?

Comment: Is it possible that you are confusing the strike price of the option as a 'buy' price? They are not the same thing.

Comment: Need to specify country. I believe in the United States, the number of shares of a corporation needs to be specified by its charter (and amendments), which is publicly filed with the state government authority in charge of companies.

Comment: @Fabio this is confusing. You typically don't "buy" stock options: they are granted by the company as a part of your compensation. Once they are vested you can choose the "exercise" them, i.e. buy actual stock at the strike price of the option. Before the exercise the employee doesn't pay for anything.

Comment: @Hilmar, yes, your way of describing is more accurate. And this is the problem, why would my friend stay in the company for several more years if they don't know what a share is going to be (meaning, % of the business)?

Comment: @FabioMilheiro Okay yes it is 100% commonplace that *exercising* the options will cost $, but getting them initially is commonly at no cost. This greatly changes my answer below. "Why would my friend stay there" - presumably they also receive a salary, etc..

Comment: Note that typically, an employee is unable to exercise options received until some milestone that makes the shares liquid - like an IPO where the shares received would be publicly listed. In that case, you would only choose to exercise them if the market price of shares is higher than the exercise price, meaning there is no risk that you exercise them and lose money, because you would simply instead choose to not use them.

Comment: Overall, I would suggest based on your confusion of the terms that you avoid giving your friend advice in this matter, as you don't want to misinterpret something and give poor advice if you are not comfortable in this area.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon, I appreciate your effort in sharing your knowledge but I know I don't know everything. That is why I asked the question. It's unfortunate I didn't make myself understood from the beginning but here is the bit that bothers me (next comment).

Comment: What if the investors paid $1 per share in the last funding round and my friend has to pay $10 when the time comes. Do you think that is right?
The investors must have known how much of the business they were buying. Why can't employees know how much of the business will they be allowed to buy?

Comment: @FabioMilheiro At the point in time where it will become possible to *exercise* the shares [which, in most employment situations, is the only time when you would actually pay money], they should have access to that information. Most likely at that point, it would be a public company so share value would be readily apparent. In the meantime, it is often recommended to consider stock options from a non-public employer as a trivial benefit; nothing to lose sleep over, but not to be forgotten about either.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon, I appreciate you having a different perspective. I thought a little bit about it but this is a company who received a lot of money in a series B funding round and has revenue over that and growing very fast. In this particular case, I do think it's very likely that it will either be bought or, most likely, go to IPO in which case if we only care about the % of the company then, then my friend was already fooled by then. They are being asked to stay over another period of 4 years in the company - finding out that time was waster would be very upsetting to say the least.

Comment: What are the terms of the options? You keep adding in meaningless hypotheticals, "what if investors paid $1, but your strike price is $10, is that fair?" Yes. An anecdote for you: I wrote the biggest check of my life, by a lot, buying stock in the company I work for (and took a loan from the company at the same time to buy more than I had cash for) so far that was the best decision of my life. I have no idea what percent of the company I own. I'm sure it's not much. What is it worth minus what did it cost; and what are the circumstances under which I can sell. That's all that matters.

Comment: @quid Just to add context for your answer which might be relevant based on what I perceive as the OP's level of understanding - could you confirm that while you don't know what the *number of shares are*, you at least have a good method of independently *assessing their fair value*? ie: it is a public company with listed share price, or perhaps shareholder agreement dictates cashout value based on some formula [which can happen particularly in employee-owned companies with Universal Shareholder Agreements at least in Canada]? Just to show you didn't pay blindly.

Comment: I'm not saying this person should buy, I'd steer clear of buying options in a private company; but we don't know the terms of the options. What was the [hypothetical] price in the last funding round, or do you think an IPO is imminent? Isn't relevant. The question is lacking all relevant details, the comments aren't filling in any blanks. I'm sure there was a cap table or something somewhere in one of the many pages I had to sign, it was all very formal involving well established PEs and law firms at the time of a PE transaction.  But I didn't care that I was buying 0.1% equity (or whatever).

Answer (score 1):

Because they don't want other people to know. There's no incentive for the company to share this information with you or anybody else. Why would they want your friend to know how much (or little) of the company your they are getting? They also don't want this information getting into the wild for the world to know.

But it DOES matter, and your friend should press for this. However, unless they are a particularly desirable or high-level candidate, they are unlikely to be successful.

Your friend might still choose to join the company even if they don't have all the information, but it's a bigger gamble and they need to know that they might not really have that much value in the options and consider the offer accordingly.

I've joined companies without knowing what fraction of the company my options represented and not regretted it. It is what it is.

Also, they should be very clear what the vesting schedule and triggers are. If they leave after 18 months, while the company is still private, do they keep any of the options? VERY important question! It is trendy these days (for tax reasons) for vesting to require both time AND a "liquidity event" (going public, getting acquired, etc). So your friend can get trapped where they have $1M in unvested options that they don't want to leave behind ("golden handcuffs"), but those options may NEVER vest.

Answer (score -1):

You seem not to understand how stock option work, which makes it difficult to answer your question.

Here is quick overview:.

1. Stock options granted to an employee as part of their compensation and/or hiring bonus.
2. Stock options give the owner the right to buy stock in the future at a specific price, called "the strike price" which is typically the fair market value at time of grant
3. Initially stock options are worthless: in order for them to create value the share price needs to go up.
4. Stock options "vest" over time, i.e. you can only exercise after a waiting period (typically 4 years with partial vesting after one year).
5. The employee doesn't have to pay anything until they choose to exercise any options
6. Typically you don't exercise unless there is a way to actual sell the shares. That's easiest if the share are publicly traded, but there are other mechanisms as well.
7. Exercising option and selling shares can have very complicated tax implications: it's strongly recommended that you discuss this with a financial advisor first. Some people in the US have been bankrupted by this!

> why is the total number of shares a secret?

Because it doesn't matter. You are not getting "a percentage of the company" you are getting the right to buy shares for a certain price in the future.

In order to valuate the stock options you need to guestimate what the stock price in the future will be. For a non-public company the share price is typically set by the board of directors in regulars intervals, so you can track this and see where it goes. The total number of outstanding shares simply isn't relevant for the value of your options.

Comment: This is the opposite of true. It matters greatly. They are paying you with options on a percentage of the company - an unknown percentage that depends on how many total shares are outstanding.

Comment: "*For a non-public company the share price is typically set by the board of directors in regulars intervals, so you can track this and see where it goes.*" While this is possible and I have seen it myself, I would not say it is common - I would say it is more common that the only way to sell shares in a private company is to find a buyer yourself, perhaps even with limitations on who is allowed to buy shares as dictated by the incorporating documents. The key question to OP's friend is - *is there a method of actually cashing these shares out, and do you know how to estimate that price now?"

Comment: "to valuate the stock options you need to guestimate what the stock price in the future will be."
Don't you also need to know the strike price, which you would subtract from the future stock price?